# iMac with OSX El Capitan does not read inserted CD or DVD

Tags: imac

In June 2018 I installed  El Capitan on my iMac2009, until then my built-in optical drive worked just fine. Now I can insert music cd's or movie dvd's but I do not get an image on my desktop. 
I suspect the cd does not enter the drive completely, as the tiniest bit sticks out and I can eject the cd with my fingernails. Anybody ever had this problem and solved it?

Comment: A visit to the apple store should help

Comment: It's a mechanical issue with the CD/DVD drive.  You can change it out or what's probably easier and cheaper is to get a USB DVD.  It's what I use on my iMac that came without a drive and it works just fine.